# Older US Utility Application

Tags: claims, international, utility

... that I am wanting international coverage but cannot as the time to do so has expired. I have designed a new component that works with the old claims as a single unit. Can I resume international patents and thereby get some degree of "perceived" protection on the original idea?

thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 1):

If you have something now that, as a whole, is novel, has an inventive step (an inventive step beyond everything that has ever been done including your old version) and industrial applicability and that whole has not yet been publicly disclosed then go for it. If you make and sell the new version very successfully someone who looks into it might realize that they could compete with you by making the old version or they might not figure that out. Also, if people would rather have the new version and the improvement doesn't add a lot of cost, that would be a factor in your market success.